# Inputting lengths and angles to determine whether it is a square, rectangle, a rhombus, or parallelogram

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, logical-operators, comparison-operators

I am very new to JavaScript, and so I am here to ask for help on how to make my code more efficient, using less lines of code, improve readability or if anybody spots any errors. I am always keen on receiving constructive criticism on where to improve.

```js
let start = alert(
  "This is a shape detector program.\nYou will be asked to enter four sides and four angles to determine the quadrilateral."
);

let obj = {};
for (let s = 1; s <= 4; s++) {
  obj[`side${s}`] = Number(prompt(`Define length ${s}: `));
}
const { side1, side2, side3, side4 } = obj;

let obj2 = {};
for (let a = 1; a <= 4; a++) {
  obj2[`corner${a}`] = Number(prompt(`Define angle ${a}: `));
}
const { corner1, corner2, corner3, corner4 } = obj2;

//if...else if...else statement
if (side1 === side3 &&
  side2 === side4 &&
  side1 === side4 &&
  corner2 === 90 &&
  corner4 === 90 &&
  corner1 === 90 &&
  corner3 === 90) {
  console.log("This is a square."); //Square: all sides equal, all corners 90 degrees
} else if (side1 === side3 &&
  side2 === side4 &&
  corner2 === 90 &&
  corner4 === 90 &&
  corner1 === 90 &&
  corner3 === 90) {
  console.log("This is a Rectangle."); //Rectangle: opposite sides equal, all corners 90 degrees.
} else if (side1 === side3 &&
  side2 === side4 &&
  side1 === side4 &&
  corner1 < 90 &&
  corner3 < 90 &&
  corner2 > 90 &&
  corner4 > 90) {
  console.log("This is a Rhombus."); //Rhombus: all sides equal, opposite angles equal. Two opposite corners are less than 90 degrees,the other two corners are more than 90 degrees.
} else if (side1 === side3 &&
  side2 === side4 &&
  corner2 > 90 &&
  corner4 > 90 &&
  corner1 < 90 &&
  corner3 < 90) {
  console.log("This is a Parallelogram."); //Parallelogram: Opposite sides equal, opposite angles equal. Two opposite corners are less than 90 degrees, the other two corners are more than 90 degrees.
} else {
  console.log("The determined shape is neither a square, rhombus, rectangle or parallelogram.");
}
```

Comment: Use arrays. Faster and you can skip the spread.

Answer (score 0):

You can save using arrays

```js
let start = alert(
  "This is a shape detector program.\nYou will be asked to enter four sides and four angles to determine the quadrilateral."
);

const sides = Array.from({length:4}).map((_,i) => +prompt(`Define length ${i+1}: `));
const corners = Array.from({length:4}).map((_,i) => +prompt(`Define angle ${i+1}: `));
const ninety = corners.every(corner => corner === 90)


//if...else if...else statement
if (sides[0] === sides[1] &&
  sides[1] === sides[2] &&
  sides[2] === sides[3] && ninety) {
  console.log("This is a square."); //Square: all sides equal, all corners 90 degrees
} else if (sides[0] === sides[2] &&
  sides[1] === sides[3] && ninety) {
  console.log("This is a Rectangle."); //Rectangle: opposite sides equal, all corners 90 degrees.
} else if (sides[0] === sides[2] &&
  sides[1] === sides[3] &&
  sides[0] === sides[3] &&
  corners[0] < 90 &&
  corners[2] < 90 &&
  corners[1] > 90 &&
  corners[3] > 90) {
  console.log("This is a Rhombus."); //Rhombus: all sides equal, opposite angles equal. Two opposite corners are less than 90 degrees,the other two corners are more than 90 degrees.
} else if (sides[0] === sides[2] &&
  sides[1] === sides[3] &&
  corners[1] > 90 &&
  corners[3] > 90 &&
  corners[0] < 90 &&
  corners[2] < 90) {
  console.log("This is a Parallelogram."); //Parallelogram: Opposite sides equal, opposite angles equal. Two opposite corners are less than 90 degrees, the other two corners are more than 90 degrees.
} else {
  console.log("The determined shape is neither a square, rhombus, rectangle or parallelogram.");
}
```